# How does recursive CTE work with example in the doc?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I was studying the CTE docs today and playing around with an example below (slightly modified from the example in the doc):

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1), (2)
  UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT n + 1
      FROM t
      WHERE n < 100
    )
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

This piece of code outputs

```
n
-----
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
10
11
11
12
12
13
13
...
```

Which is fine by itself. However, in the doc, the explanation goes like the following (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html):

> 1. Evaluate the non-recursive term. For `UNION` (but not `UNION ALL`),
>      discard duplicate rows. Include all remaining rows in the result of
>      the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary *working*
>      table.
> 2. So long as the working table is not empty, repeat these steps:
>
>    1. Evaluate the recursive term, substituting the current contents of
>         the working table for the recursive self-reference. For `UNION` (but
>         not `UNION ALL`), discard duplicate rows and rows that duplicate any
>         previous result row. Include all remaining rows in the result of the
>         recursive query, and also place them in a temporary *intermediate*
>         table.
>    2. Replace the contents of the working table with the contents of the intermediate table, then empty the intermediate table.

My interpretation of the explanations is as follows:

Initially, we insert `(1), (2)` into the working table. Then in the recursive step, we take the working table, which currently has `(1), (2)`, `UNION ALL` the results of the recursive step, which returns `(2), (3)`, and then place the results into *intermediate table*.

So after the first recursive call, we have `(1), (2)` in *working table* and `(1), (2), (2), (3)` in *intermediate table*.

Then we replace the values of *working table* with the values of *intermediate table*, and then empty out the *intermediate table*. So now *working table* has `(1), (2), (2), (3)` and *intermediate table* is empty.

Now next recursive call, we will take the *working table* which contains `(1), (2), (2), (3)`, recurse on it, which yields `(2), (3), (3), (4)`, and append it to the working table. So the working table now **should** have `(1), (2), (2), (3), (2), (3), (3), (4)`. However, the results starts with 
`(1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3), (4), (4)` etc.

Can anyone let me know where I went wrong in my line of reasoning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37880628/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing ***result*** and ***intermediate table***, which are not the same.

`(1), (2)` is produced by the "non-recursive" term and placed in the *result*.
`(1), (2)` also goes into the *working table*.
-- start iteration here
`(2), (3)` is produced by the "recursive" term and added to the *result*.
`(2), (3)` are also placed in an *intermediate table*.
`(2), (3)` the content of the *intermediate table* is moved to the *working table*.
--  iterate

As the manual adds right there ([link to the *current* manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)):

> Strictly speaking, this process is iteration not recursion, but `RECURSIVE` is the terminology chosen by the SQL standards committee.

Not related to your particular misunderstanding, just to explain my quotes around "recursive".

Answer (score 0):

```
1,2             = 1,2 -> keep
1,2 plus 1 = 2,3 -> keep
2,3 plus 1 = 3,4 -> keep
3,4 plus 1 = 4,5 -> keep
```

The result is 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5, ....

The working table has only the immediately  prior result