# How do recursive SQL Querys terminate and how do they get evaluated?

Tags: sql, recursion

I ran over the following code

[image: https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/]

I just cannot grasp how the computer would possibly evaluate such code such that cte_count will ever terminate.

**In my mind it works like this:**

1. *cte_count* is a table which contains a column called n containing 1 and the result of (Recursive Member)

First of all: Whatis *n + 1* supposed to mean? n is the name of a column, as far as I am concerned.

Assuming that *n + 1* just increases somehow a counter:
Secondly, how will the termination condition ever be checked, when *cte_count* will be evaluated before.

I hope someone can make clearer how such Queries work.

Comment: `WHERE n < 50` terminates the recursion.

Comment: `n + 1` is an expression that returns the increased value, still as column name n (as specified in the UNION ALL's first SELECT.=

Comment: When does n < 50 get checked???

Comment: For each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just cannot grasp how the computer would possibly evaluate such code such that `cte_count` will ever terminate.

Well the short answer is that it does not know.
The recursive CTE will only recurs maximum of 32,767 times or infinitely. See official [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation and then throws signal that maximum recursion value is reached. Exact number of maximum recursion can be set using `MAXRECURSION` property (with `0` meaning infinite).

Yes `N` is the name of column. And the recursion query part

```
select n+1  from cte_count where n<50
```

is a shorthand for

```
select n+1  as n from cte_count where n<50
```

in this case as unnamed column in the union all clause takes the same datatype and name as the similarly positioned column in the upper part of the `UNION ALL` syntax.

so imagine starting the CTE with select 1 as N pushed into a table `cte_count` with single column `N` like so

| N |
| --- |
| 1 |

and then first recursion operates on this table to give result

| N |
| --- |
| 2 |

These two are union all-ed to give new cte_count table as

| N |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

next recursion uses the above table as input to give result as

| N |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

which is union all-ed with existing cte_count table to give updated cte_count as

| N |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Comment: So n +1 means that every element in N gets increased by one?

Comment: Does this further mean that SQL is indeed calculating these expressions takes 32,767 recursions?

Comment: @Niclas I wanted to answer this but then I found an excellent answer related to postgres sql but it does explain the logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015842/how-sql-with-recursive-statement-interpreted